# GridView styling

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have problem with Gridview styling. I want to set more space between each two columns. I tried command cellpadding and cellspacing, but it does not work. Thanks for your ideas and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply apply a style, eg on the GridView you set `CssClass="gvMoreSpace"` and this style can be:

```
<style type="text/css">
      .gvMoreSpace tr td
      {
        padding:0 0 0 10px;
      }
</style>
```

Some more details, the GridView is render as table, is you look on the source code you can see that, then by apply a style name, you can do whatever you like to that table.